# Pass a model as a function parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I found the below code in C#.

`var results= context.Database.SqlQuery <Student> ("select * from students").ToList();`

would give me a list of Students and

`var results= context.Database.SqlQuery <Teacher> ("select * from teachers").ToList();`

would give me a list of teachers. These seem very similar to me. What I want to do is make the above into a function that takes a model and a string so I can just pass something like

```
GetList(Model myModel, string sqlString)
{
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<myModel>(sqlString).ToList();
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: it's the same thing. Both call the same method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want Your function to return List of Your model class, make Your function use `generic type`:

```
        List<T> GetList<T>(string sqlString)
        {
            return context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlString).ToList();
        }
```

Usage is very simple:

```
List<YourModel> yourList = GetList<YourModel>(sqlString);
```

This function will return list of any type for You.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking into using generics.

Your method would look something like this:

```
GetList<T>(string sqlString)
{
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlString).ToList();
}
```

and then you'd call it replacing the `T` with your type, so :

```
var list = GetList<MyModel>("select * from table");
```

read about generics [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-generics-introduction/)